# looping over optional arguments (strings) in python

Tags: python, optional-arguments

I have lists of strings, some are hashtags - like #rabbitsarecool others are short pieces of prose like "My rabbits name is fred."

I have written a program to seperate them:

```
def seperate_hashtags_from_prose(*strs):
    props    = []
    hashtags = []
    for x in strs:
        if x[0]=="#" and x.find(' ')==-1:
            hashtags += x
        else:
            prose    += x
    return hashtags, prose

seperate_hashtags_from_prose(["I like cats","#cats","Rabbits are the best","#Rabbits"])
```

This program does not work. in the above example when i debug it, it tells me that on the first loop:

```
x=["I like cats","#cats","Rabbits are the best",#Rabbits].
```

Thisis not what I would have expected - my intuition is that something about the way the loop over optional arguments is constructed is causing an error- but i can't see why.

Comment: As far as Python is concerned, you passed your function a single argument: a list. Pass it in as several arguments (by deleting the brackets), or change the function signature to expect a list.

Comment: Unclear what your desired output is. Please include in your post the current output and the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues.

1. The most obvious is switching between `props` and `prose`. The code you posted does not run.
2. As others have commented, if you use the `*` in the function call, you should not make the call with a list. You could use `seperate_hashtags_from_prose("I like cats","#cats","Rabbits are the best","#Rabbits")` instead.
3. The line `hashtags += x` does not do what you think it does. When you use `+` as an operator on iterables (such as `list` and `string`) it will concatenate them. You probably meant `hashtags.append(x)` instead.